# How to record MS-DOS application into video file

Tags: video, software-rec, ms-dos

I have an old application for MS-DOS. It works in graphic mode (13H, 320x240) and it is actually a some kind graphical demo presentation.

What I would like to do is to record its running. I am using Windows XP. The only solution that came to my mind is to use VCR/DVDR recorder equipment connected to the computer, but it's rather impossible for me.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run it in a virtual machine, and use a regular Windows screen recorder.

For example, someone [upgraded through every version of Windows](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vPnehDhGa14) starting with DOS 5. He used VMWare, partly because of its "excellent video recording". But you might try others, like Virtual PC or VirtualBox.

Comment: +1 for the link to that youtube video. Very interesting.